# Using Jfilechooser, getting some funky filenames

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I have started seeing some odd behaviour on a few of our computers when using `JFileChooser`.

I get the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbcky.jpg

(cant post the image because i am missing 10 reputation :))

(The files are not intended to be named !!!! and numbers)

I have used the following code to confirm there is something wrong not only with my program.

**code:**

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class asdfghjkl {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);

        int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(new Frame());
        if(returnVal> 0){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

}
```

When opening in windows file explorer the files are displayed just as one would expect.
Little lost on this one, hope anyone can provide some ideas or input!

update 1.

I got around to do abit more digging around. The is nothing particular in the file names. All the !!!! named files/folders do not exist in file explorer. See this image for comparison. imgur.com/FuOcHH4 Still equally stumped...

Comment: Looks sort of like weird encoding issue. Would I be correct in thinking that all the folders that display wrong names have non-ascii characters in them?

Comment: I think you are right about the encoding, but i have not defined the encoding anywhere...

I dont think that all of them have non-ascii characters, a few might have æøå, but nothing else that is "special"

Comment: I got around to do abit more digging around.
The is nothing particular in the file names.
All the !!!! named files/folders do not exist in file explorer.

See this image for comparison.
https://imgur.com/FuOcHH4

Still equally stumped...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, turned out to be our antivirus/malware system that generated a ton of hidden files, these files does not appear in windows explorer, but can appear in other software that looks through the files on a given computer.